# Fabric Smart Contracts in Kotlin

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

We are looking at building smart contracts in Kotlin language, even though its not officially a supported language. The reasons are -

- It compiles down to Java bytecode.. So from a JVM point of view, its no different to java
- Its a very expressive language with a much better type system than java.
- Its got first hand support for functional programming constructs.

So, the question I have is not about technical feasibility - coz I know its not a problem. The question is, does anyone see any other issues with this approach? Perhaps anything core to Hyperledger Fabric which might cause issues further down the line? Also, curious if anyone else has tried this before in a production set up? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone has used it in production, and/or hit any problems using Kotlin, but there is a [Kotlin example in the Java chaincode repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java/tree/main/examples/fabric-contract-example-gradle-kotlin).